# Where to start with pseudo bubble sort or average top 4 values

Tags: sorting, parsing, gps, nmea

I'm using an Arduino Leonardo and a GPSTiny++ library to parse NMEA strings from my GPS receiver. In this chunk of code I'm averaging all satellite SNR numbers for satellites which are locked (Being used for navigation). The avg value provides some general information on overall performance but I'm also really looking for the avg Top 4 values.

I believe I would need to do some sort of sorting algorithm. Increment through the top 4 and average those values.

Here's a snippet of my output window:
12/13 0.92 SNR=17 10 27 27 30 29 25 27 33 0 0 0 31 25.60 0.00

The second to last number is the average.

How do I get started?

```
int totalSNR = 0;
    float avgSNR = 0;
    int count = 0;
    Serial.print(F(" SNR="));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SATELLITES; ++i)
      if (sats[i].active)
      {
        if (sats[i].snr > 0) {
          count++;
          totalSNR = totalSNR + sats[i].snr;
        }

        Serial.print(sats[i].snr);
        Serial.print(F(" "));
      }

    avgSNR = float(totalSNR) / float(count);
    Serial.print(avgSNR);
```

Comment: So you dont have a sort() libray function? which programming language?

Comment: I'm using the Arduino IDE. I'll check for a sort() function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:
Create an array with your values, then sort that array. 
This will give you an array of values arranged with the highest value in element number 1 and the lowest value in the last element.
The top 4 will then be your top 4 highest values. You can then add those together and divide by 4 to get the average of the top 4 highest.
Make sure that the array size is the same as "MAX_SATELLITES".

```
for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_SATELLITES; ++i)  
{  
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SATELLITES; ++j)   
    {  
        if (VALUES_ARRAY[j] < VALUES_ARRAY[j+1])  
        {  
            VALUE_HIGH = VALUES_ARRAY[j+1];  
            VALUE_LOW = VALUES_ARRAY[j];  
        else  
            VALUE_HIGH = VALUES_ARRAY[j];  
            VALUE_LOW = VALUES_ARRAY[j+1];  
        }  
        VALUES_ARRAY[j] = VALUE_HIGH;  
        VALUES_ARRAY[j+1] = VALUE_LOW;  
    }  
}
```